# Angular js trigger an ng-class toggle from the directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive which is triggered to hide an element when a condition is reached.

```
     var hideElement = function(){
            el = element.find('.myelement');
            $(el).addClass('hideme');                          
     };
```

then in a conditional I trigger the hideElement function

```
 if(j >= count){
      hideElement ();
 }
```

how do I refactor this on the partial to make a change to the ng-class?

```
<div 
    data-directivename 
    data-increment="increment" 
    data-count="count" 
    ng-class="{'timetohide': hide}"
>
    <div class="myelement"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a scope variable:

```
var hideElement = function(){
    scope.hide = true;
};
```

And then, your `ng-class="{'timetohide': hide}"` will work just fine - the element will get the `timetohide` class when `scope.hide` is truthy.

---

UPDATE

Since you're using isolated scope in the directive, you actually need to modify the parent scope variable because that's what the ng-class is watching, so the code from above should be:

```
var hideElement = function(){
    scope.$parent.hide = true;
};
```

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dXSi5hH4FEVQuDS9uMOl?p=preview (the version after all our comments)

Explanation from: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

> Scope : { } ( Directive gets a new isolated scope )
>
> This is the most interesting section. Till now, we saw two situations for directive scope creation. In the third type, we are going to set scope property in DDO to an Object literal. When an object literal is passed to the scope property, things are bit different. This time, there will be a new scope created for the directive, but it will not be inherited from the parent scope. This new scope also known as Isolated scope because it is completely detached from its parent scope.

Makes sense.

Comment: I don't get this - it comes out as class="ng-isolate-scope"

Comment: Yes, and when `scope.hide` becomes truthy, ng-class would change the class to `"ng-isolate-scope timetohide"`.

Comment: No man, its not taking it - do I need to define the scope/ am I overwriting it? Do I need to include hide?

Comment: return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: linker,
                controller: ctrl,
                scope: {                   
                    increment: "=",
                    count: "=",
                }
            };

Comment: It should be inside the directive controller, so you're using the existing scope, here's an example for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/MydPkayUcmJYjO0AVWhz?p=preview (it goes red instead of hidden, click to toggle it)

Comment: I've defined the $scope.isHide = false in the controller - and in the directive - where the logic is I can set the scope.isHide from false to true. But it doesn't make an impact on the ng-class

Comment: And here it is using both controller and linker with isolated scopes: http://plnkr.co/edit/WMXXjf0QW8xieuQhx9Mv?p=preview

Comment: Hmmm, is your ng-class set to use `isHide` instead of `hide`? Like this: `ng-class="{'timetohide': isHide}"`. Ng-class format is `{className: scopeVariable}`.

Comment: I don't think so - check the code above in the answer there

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

Ng:

```
scope.someCondition = true;
```

HTML

```
<div class="myelement" ng-show="someCondition"></div>
```

Comment: May have a similar problem trying to invoke a change in ng-show - I've posted the directive/controller setup - its like this because I am changing values inside the directive from another

Answer (score -1):

My controller and directive

```
return angular.module("portal").directive("doughnutIncrementor", [
        "Account",
        "Common",
        function (Account, Common) {
            var ctrl, linker;

            ctrl = function($scope){
                $scope.increment = 15;
                $scope.count = 5;
                $scope.isHide = false;
            },
            linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {


                var hideDoughnutIndicator = function(){
                    console.log('scope hide', scope.isHide); //here it is false as it should be
                    scope.isHide = true;
                    console.log('scope hide', scope.isHide); //then it becomes true - but has no impact on the ng-class which remains as "ng-isolate-scope"            
                };


                var j = 1;
                scope.$watch(attrs.increment, function(value) {
                    if(j >= scope.count){
                        hideDoughnutIndicator();
                    }
                    j++;
                });
            };

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                templateUrl: Common.paths.partials + '/doughnut-incrementor.html',
                link: linker,
                controller: ctrl,
                scope: {                   
                    increment: "=",
                    count: "=",
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

my partial

```
<div data-doughnut-incrementor data-increment="increment" data-count="count" ng-class="{hide : isHide}"></div>
```

Comment: It sets the scope.isHide to true - but the class doesn't get affected - whats wrong

Comment: I've also tried wrapping it in an $apply but then it gets an error saying "$digest already in progress".                  var hideDoughnutIndicator = function(){
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.isHide = true;
                    });
                };

Comment: doughnut-incrementor.html actually has an emtpy div  "<div class="doughnutindicator" data-initial-value="5" data-radius=120></div>"

Comment: Seems like a directive scope issue, I'll let you know in a minute

Comment: Its complex - because I change the increment outside of this directive - and that part works fine, but its then appending this ng-class - which is a problem

Comment: I've updated my answer. For some reason ng-class is not looking into the controller scope, but the isolated directive scope, and the properties of the isolated scope are not inherited so you need to specifically define the isHide property inside the $parent scope... very interesting issue. :)

Comment: $parent scope - what would this look like?

Comment: $scope.$parent... which actually matches the rootScope in our case. See the plunker in my answer. Btw. I think you should probably remove this "answer", or move it inside your question.

Comment: Where is your answer? 'Cannot set property 'isHide' of undefined' ctrl = function($scope){
                $scope.increment = 15;
                $scope.count = 5;
                $scope.parent.isHide = false;
            }

Comment: var hideDoughnutIndicator = function(){
                    scope.parent.isHide = true;
                };

Comment: My original answer, it's updated. It should be `scope.$parent.isHide = true;` (the dollar sign on parent)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MydPkayUcmJYjO0AVWhz?p=preview ? I only see two panes where do you make the parent.scope change?

Comment: angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };
    }])
    .directive('dirTest', function() {
      return {
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.hide = true;
        }
      };
    });

Comment: I see it - but it still doesn't work for me. I am not using a click trigger to invoke it - if there is a setTimeOut inside the directive itself to change the scope after say 3 seconds - would it then auto change your example?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0YdZqKqvFEObrCSYOTII?p=preview - I've added a timeout - which mimics that a change occurs inside the directive and tries to set the scope isHide to true - the logic seems to work - but it still doesn't trigger the change on the page

Comment: No, click and the timeout have nothing to do with it. You need to change the parent scope property in the linker as well (scope.$parent.isHide)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1wtgmGBasiZ4GtCb7pdo?p=preview that still doesn't affect it?

Comment: Because Angular doesn't know about the setTimeout changes - either use $timeout or manually run scope.$apply: http://plnkr.co/edit/QoL7wOg3j1omldpcEgHh?p=preview

Comment: This looks good - but on my actual application I get the error - "$digest already in progress"

Comment: Then you can omit the apply thing since something else is triggering it anyway.

Comment: Its back to the same problem I was having. I set the variable scope.$parent.isHide = true; - but then it does not change the class on the front end. Your apply solution - I saw the change occur on your test page. But then when I do that, it throws up digest already in progress.

Comment: Try to use as much as you can from that last plunker... I don't know what else to say. :) To avoid the digest issue, wrap the function inside a $timeout call.

Comment: I've tried this - no error - but no result in changing the class?                 var hideDoughnutIndicator = function(){
                    scope.$parent.isHide = true;
                    console.log('hide the div', scope.$parent.isHide);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            console.log('do it');
                            scope.$parent.isHide = true;
                            //$scope.message = "Timeout called!";
                        });
                    }, 2000);

                };

Comment: Last idea: try scope.$parent.$apply instead.

Comment: Is this relevant maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304673/ng-class-will-not-trigger-on-custom-directive

Comment: I'd say it is, but we have a working plunker as a counter-argument.